# PHP average by group of n elements in an array

Tags: php

I have an array which is created by uploading and reading an excel file.

The script for creating array is this:

```
$values = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    $date = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
    $dir = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
    $sinvalue= sin(deg2rad($dir));
    $cosvalue= cos(deg2rad($dir));            
    $values[] = "('$date', $sinvalue,$cosvalue)";
}
```

This array is working. Typically it has 1440 elements.  I want to take average of `$sinvalue` and `$cosvalue` in group of 5 starting from first element. Further out of this average of 5 (it will be 288 elements) , I want to find average in group of 12. Finally there will be 24 values. How to make a for loop for this?

Data llook like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => ('date', 0,1) 
    [1] => ('2018-01-23 00:01:00', -0.374606593415912,-0.9271838545667874) 
    [2] => ('2018-01-23 00:02:00', -0.4383711467890778,0.8987940462991668) 
    [3] => ('2018-01-23 00:03:00', 0.6946583704589975,-0.719339800338651) 
    [4] => ('2018-01-23 00:04:00', 0.9063077870366499,0.4226182617406994) 
    [5] => ('2018-01-23 00:05:00', -0.9510565162951535,-0.3090169943749476) 
    [6] => ('2018-01-23 00:06:00', -0.743144825477394,-0.6691306063588585) 
    [7] => ('2018-01-23 00:07:00', 0.9876883405951378,0.1564344650402309) 
    [8] => ('2018-01-23 00:08:00', -0.7986355100472928,-0.6018150231520483) 
    [9] => ('2018-01-23 00:09:00', 0.2079116908177593,-0.9781476007338057) 
    [10] => ('2018-01-23 00:10:00', 0.2756373558169992,-0.9612616959383189) 
    [11] => ('2018-01-23 00:11:00', -0.9396926207859082,-0.3420201433256694) 
    [12] => ('2018-01-23 00:12:00', -0.4539904997395462,-0.8910065241883681) 
    [13] => ('2018-01-23 00:13:00', 0.9961946980917455,0.08715574274765836) 
    [14] => ('2018-01-23 00:14:00', -0.6819983600624984,-0.7313537016191706) 
    [15] => ('2018-01-23 00:15:00', -0.9961946980917455,0.08715574274765789) 
    [16] => ('2018-01-23 00:16:00', 0.4067366430758,-0.913545457642601) 
    [17] => ('2018-01-23 00:17:00', -0.5000000000000001,-0.8660254037844386) 
    [18] => ('2018-01-23 00:18:00', 0.9135454576426009,0.4067366430758004) 
    [19] => ('2018-01-23 00:19:00', 0.819152044288992,-0.5735764363510458) 
    [20] => ('2018-01-23 00:20:00', 0.6946583704589975,-0.719339800338651) 
    [21] => ('2018-01-23 00:21:00', 0.7986355100472928,0.6018150231520484) 
    [22] => ('2018-01-23 00:22:00', 0.8746197071393959,-0.484809620246337) 
    [23] => ('2018-01-23 00:23:00', -0.2249510543438653,0.9743700647852351) 
    [24] => ('2018-01-23 00:24:00', 0.6427876096865393,0.766044443118978) 
    [25] => ('2018-01-23 00:25:00', 0.5877852522924732,-0.8090169943749473) 
    [26] => ('2018-01-23 00:26:00', 0.7986355100472928,0.6018150231520484) 
    [27] => ('2018-01-23 00:27:00', 0.992546151641322,0.1218693434051475) 
    [28] => ('2018-01-23 00:28:00', -0.9961946980917455,0.08715574274765789) 
    [29] => ('2018-01-23 00:29:00', 0.9335804264972017,0.3583679495453002) 
    [30] => ('2018-01-23 00:30:00', -0.961261695938319,-0.2756373558169989) 
    [31] => ('2018-01-23 00:31:00', 0.4383711467890777,-0.8987940462991668) 
    [32] => ('2018-01-23 00:32:00', -0.9993908270190958,0.03489949670250039) 
    [33] => ('2018-01-23 00:33:00', -0.743144825477394,-0.6691306063588585) 
)
```

Comment: You're better off with providing use an example of how the data looks, not how you've made it. Also, what have you tried so far, what problems have you come up against?

Comment: is the first key element in `$allDataInSheet` 0 or 1?

Comment: It is 1 because 1 row is column heading

Comment: `array_chunk()` and `array_sum(array_column($array,1))` will help you

Comment: The data you supplied doesn't quite match `$allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]` which says you have an associative array. Should this be `$allDataInSheet[$i][1]`? or `$allDataInSheet[$i][2]`? What's the significance between those two values because as far as I can tell, you only ever use one of them in your code and share it with sin/cos

Comment: First column in excel file contains datetime and second column direction in degrees.. I want sin and cos values of the radian of the direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should redesign your data structure. You aggregate the values in strings in `$values` and then it's difficult to extract and use the individual components.

```
$values = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    $date = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
    $dir = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
    $sinvalue= sin(deg2rad($dir));
    $cosvalue= cos(deg2rad($dir));            
    $values[] = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'sin'  => $sinvalue,
        'cos'  => $cosvalue,
    );
}
```

Now, several [array functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) can be applied to do the job.

PHP does not provide a function to compute the average for a list of numbers but it is not difficult to write one:

```
function average(array $input)
{
    return array_sum($input) / count($input);
}
```

Extract the values associated to `'sin'` in `$values`, split the list in chunks of 5 items, apply the function `average()` to each chunk. The result is a list of 288 values.

```
$avg288 = array_map(
    'average',
    array_chunk(
        array_column($values, 'sin'),
        5
    )
);
```

Similar to above, split the list of 288 averages into 24 chunks of 12 values, apply `average()` to each chunk, get a list of 24 numbers.

```
$avg24 = array_map(
    'average',
    array_chunk(
        $avg288,
        12
    )
);
```

Read about [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php), [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php), [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php), [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php), [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

---

**Update**

On PHP 5.4 [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) doesn't work (because it was introduced in PHP 5.5.).

In this case you can compute the array returned by [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) in the initial loop, where `$values` is created:

```
$values = array();
$sins = array();
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    $date = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["A"]);
    $dir = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);
    $sinvalue= sin(deg2rad($dir));
    $cosvalue= cos(deg2rad($dir));            
    $values[] = array(
        'date' => $date,
        'sin'  => $sinvalue,
        'cos'  => $cosvalue,
    );
    $sins[] = $sinvalue;
}
```

The use `$sins` instead of `array_column($values, 'sin')` in the computation of `$avg288`.

Comment: The code shows error with the last comma in array_map. If I remove comma, then no output comes

Comment: I tried this also $avg288 = array_map(average( array_chunk(array_column($values, 'sin'),5 )));

Comment: Calling `average(array_chunk(...))` doesn't work because [`array_chunk()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) returns a list of lists and `average()` expects a list of numbers. I removed the commas from the code and it works now. However, it doesn't expect your `$values` contain the header line (`array('date', 0,1)`).

Comment: seems that array_column not working as the PHP version is 5.4

Comment: Any work around in php 5.4, because, I am not the server administrator so up gradation is difficult

Comment: In this case you can build the output of `array_column()` in the initial loop, where you build `$values`. I updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

Although Axiac's solution is nice. I already started work on my solution before he posted. And I visit a slightly different approach. I don't use `array_map` or `array_chunk`.

My main issue, as I explained in the comments is your data structure, specificaly that in your code you are accessing the direction via an associative array;
`$dir = trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);`

But your data you supplied to us shows a normal indexed array;
`[1] => ('2018-01-23 00:01:00', -0.374606593415912,-0.9271838545667874)`

Therefore `trim($allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]);` should return "undefined index "B" ".. Anyway...
Here's my solution:

I loop through all the elements of the array, I check if it's a modular of 5 or 12. I then pass the current index to an averaging function that accesses the next 5/12 elements of the array and returns the average sin+cos in an array.

If this doesn't work, it's because of what i mentioned up above...
`$allDataInSheet[$i]["B"]` should be `$allDataInSheet[$i][1]`

```
<?php

$allDataInSheet = array();
$arrayCount = count($allDataInSheet);

$fiveGroup = array();
$twelveGroup = array();

//loop the array
for($i=1;$i<=$arrayCount;$i++){
    //modula function to see if group of 5
    if($i%5 === 0){
       $fiveGroup[] = calculateAverage($i,5,$allDataInSheet);
    //modula to see if group of 12
    }else if($i%12===0){
       $twelveGroup[] = calculateAverage($i,12,$allDataInSheet);
    }

}

//output the 5 grouped averages
print_r($fiveGroup);
//output the 12 grouped averages
print_r($twelveGroup);    


function calculateAverage($indexStart,$indexEnd,$array){
    //initilize the arrays
    $sinGroup = array();
    $cosGroup = array();

    //loop over elements
    for($i=1; $i<$indexEnd; $c++){
        //Assign the values to array
        $sinGroup[] = sin(deg2rad($array[$indexStart+$c]["B"]));
        $cosGroup[] = cos(deg2rad($array[$indexStart+$c]["B"]));
        //$sinGroup[] = sin(deg2rad($array[$indexStart+$c][1]));
        //$cosGroup[] = cos(deg2rad($array[$indexStart+$c][1]));
    }

    //work out the average
    $sinAverage = array_sum($sinGroup) / count($sinGroup);
    $cosAverage = array_sum($cosGroup) / count($cosGroup);

    //return the averages
    return array($sinAverage,$cosAverage);

}
```